# Convergent sequence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

When asked to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{{F_i} \over {10^{i+1}}}$ , where $F_i$ is fibonacci sequence, converges to a rational number, am I right to assume that it is satisfactory to prove that it converges at all? And then, is it enough to use the ratio test?

Comment: No; a converging sequence of rational numbers does not have to converge to a rational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{F_i}{10^{i+1}}=\frac{F_1}{10^2}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\sum_{i=3}^\infty\frac{F_i}{10^{i+1}}=\frac{F_1}{10^2}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\frac{1}{10^3}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{F_{i+2}}{10^i}\\
&=&\frac{F_1}{10^2}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\frac{1}{10^3}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{F_i+F_{i+1}}{10^i}=\frac{F_1}{10^2}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\frac{1}{10^2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{F_i}{10^{i+1}}+\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{F_{i+1}}{10^{i+2}}\\
&=&\frac{F_1}{10^2}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\frac{1}{10^2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{F_i}{10^{i+1}}+\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{F_i}{10^{i+1}}=\frac{F_1}{10^2}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\frac{S}{10^2}+\frac{1}{10}\left(S-\frac{F_1}{10^2}\right)\\
&=&\frac{9F_1}{10^3}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}+\frac{11S}{10^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
S=\frac{100}{89}\left(\frac{9F_1}{10^3}+\frac{F_2}{10^3}\right)=\frac{9F_1+F_2}{890}=\frac{9+1}{890}=\frac{1}{89}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ratio-test to prove the convergence of the series, but that
does not prove that the limit is a rational number.

But the *generating function*
$$
s(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n
$$
has the closed form $s(x) = x/(1-x-x^2)$, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Power_series. Therefore
$$
     \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{F_n}{10^{n+1}} = \frac1{10} \, s(\frac1{10}) = \frac 1{89}
$$
is rational.